# Usage case of object adapter pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

Is this how adapter design pattern used?

I have Draw class (implements Shapes) and Square class (implements Polygon). Now if both Draw and Square are closed to modifications and I need a square object created by the client to do the "drawing" then I go for an adapter.

Also is the below implementation object adapter pattern or the class adapter pattern?

```
interface Shapes {
    public void draw();
}

class Draw implements Shapes {

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        println("Drawing a shape");
    }
}


interface Polygon {
    public void getSides();
    public void getArea();
}

class Square implements Polygon {

    int length;

    Square(int length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public void getSides() {
        println("Sides: 4");
    }

    @Override
    public void getArea() {
        println("Area: "+length*length);
    }
}


class SquareAdapter extends Square{

    Shapes shape;

    public SquareAdapter(Shapes shape, int length){
        super(length);
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    public void draw(){
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
SquareAdapter adapter = new SquareAdapter(new Draw(), 3);
adapter.draw();
adapter.getArea();
adapter.getSides();
```

UPDATE 1: Solution

Thanks to Stanislav. I modified the example in a more fitting way.

```
interface Draw {
    public void draw();
}

class Circle implements Draw {

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        println("Drawing a circle");
    }
}


interface Polygon {
    public void getSides();
    public void getArea();
}

class Square implements Polygon {

    int length;

    Square(int length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public void getSides() {
        println("Sides: 4");
    }

    @Override
    public void getArea() {
        println("Area: "+length*length);
    }
}

//object composition adapters

class SquareAdapter implements Draw {

    Polygon square;

    public SquareAdapter(Polygon square){
        this.square = square;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(){
        println("Drawing a square");
    }

    public Polygon getSquare() {
        return square;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
Draw drawingObj = null;

//Now lets say the client wants to draw a Square but it
//doesn't implement Draw
//drawingObj = new Square();
//drawingObj.draw() //this is not possible so we write a adapter

drawingObj = new SquareAdapter(new Square(5));
drawingObj.draw();
((SquareAdapter) drawingObj).getSquare().getSides();
((SquareAdapter) drawingObj).getSquare().getArea();



//class inheritance adapters

class SquareAdapter extends Square implements Draw {

    SquareAdapter(int length) {
        super(length);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(){
        println("Drawing a square");
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
Draw drawingObj = null;

//Now lets say the client wants to draw a Square but it
//doesn't implement Draw
//drawingObj = new Square();
//drawingObj.draw() //this is not possible so we write a adapter

drawingObj = new SquareAdapter(5);
drawingObj.draw();
((Square) drawingObj).getSides();
((Square) drawingObj).getArea();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter pattern aims to be a bridge between two incompatible interfaces, but not to add a new functionality to an existing object. In your case

> Draw and Square are closed to modifications and I need a square object created by the client to do the "drawing"

it seems more as Decorator pattern, which aims to make new functionality for an existing object, without changing it's inner structure.

So, in case of Adapter pattern, your Adapter class has to implement Shapes interface, while you want it to have a draw method. Although there are 2 type of Adapters - Class and Object Adapter, both of them requires an interface implementation.

Here is the easiest Adapter implementation:

```
class SquareAdapter implements Shapes{

    Polygon square;

    public SquareAdapter(Polygon square){
        this.square = square;
    }

    public void draw(){
        //some logic to draw Square object
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the answer I added as an edit to the post above. That sample code makes sense right?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be right usage of both adapter pattern types, because in that case you can use your adapter class as instance of Shapes